# Nested array last element in object gets deleted when pushed new object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object

Please check the stackblitz.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/timesheetgenerator?file=src/app/app.component.ts
Whenever a number divisible by 8 is entered after the value which is divisible by ".5" i.e [1.5,2.5 etc], the previous object array element gets deleted.
To reproduce:
1.click submit with input 12 hours
2.you will see an object array in console
[image]
3.Enter 16 and submit in input, you will see the object as in image.

So, here the 'last value in **item** array' in Object[0] is deleted when another object is pushed.

**My Goal: Whenever a number is divisible by 8 with [1.5,2.5,3.5 ...etc], I would like to push them [2 times, 3 times, 4 times ..etc] into object array. But, when the number which is divisible by 8 is entered after this number, it deletes the last value in the array.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure you have required dependencies in stackblitz. 'xlsx' dependency

Comment: linking an entire, multi-file project is not a minimal reproducable example.

Comment: @junvar Its not a complete project. I am sorry, I know its a big file, but the loops used are same as previous one. I reduced some of it, but we need the whole thing to do it.